# Shows error with each image which is not present on the path specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using json data received from server to display images. I am getting all images path and making them a string "html" and at last using `$("#result").html(html);` to append all html to a div result.
My problem is that there are some image paths but corresponding to these paths there is no image and I want to display an error message in this case.
I can use

```
 $('img').error(function(){
    console.log('error');
});
```

but the problem is I want to add error message with each image which is not present. Unable to do it because I am displaying all images collectively at the end  using `$("#result").html(html)`
Please solve my problem.

Thanks
Romi

Comment: i think you need to first work on your acceptance and Vote cast.

Comment: Vivkek: What does it mean ??? need to work on Vote Cast n acceptance

Comment: @Romi-you should accept those answer which answered your answer corectly by clicking tick and you can vote-up too by clicking upper arrow in top left to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
 $("#result").html(html);
        $(("#result").find('img').error(function(){ 
            $(this).after("<br>Image was not found");   

            });
```

hope you can see now where the problem is :), if still not let me know.

Comment: @Vivek:Its working fine, If i put an alert box i can see that it is working. But it does not add messsge "Image not found" why is so ??

Comment: Vivek: Thanks, Now its working but working when i add this function after $("#result").html(msg);. But by doing it $(this) is not working i have to use $('img'). with this, the problem is ,it is adding msg with all the images where i just want to add message only with the image which is not in the specified path

Comment: hey!!!-hope you will getrid of your problem, now it's time to go..don't forget to upvote answer if it helps you.

Comment: @Vivek: Firstly i tried your edited answer, But it was not working thats why i did $("#result").html(html); before the $(html).find('img').error(function(), now it was working but  $(this).after("<br>Image was not found");  is still not working, when i use $('img') inplace of $(this) it works..but result is not as i expect :(

Comment: Vivek: No i am still there :(, No solution :(

Comment: yeah i just try last option in my answer

Comment: this line is not correct-`$(html).find('img').error(function(), ` you have appended your html in result div, so now you have to look into that result div in order to get wrong img, in this way- `$(("#result").find('img').error(function(){              $(this).after("<br>Image was not found");                 }); `

Comment: Vivek: this line working but the problem is it is adding message witrh all the images

Comment: yeah i saw your code, that's y i have given above comment.try out highlighted code in my comment , that will solve your problem,

Comment: hey..sorry dear now i have to go...i will see it 2mrow, if you still left with it, hope you not..happy coding:)

Comment: Vivek: http://jsfiddle.net/Romi/HnwLS/   look at this it is working fine...but my original is not fine :(

Comment: Vivek: I tried $(("#result").find('img').error(function(){ $(this).after("<br>Image was not found"); stil the problem is same :(

Comment: Vivek: Thanks a ton. Finally it is working fine :), But would you please tell me one thing. Actually i wanted to display message as an error message but using  $(this).after("<br>Image was not found");  , it adds message same as alt. by looking at it one can not say whether it is a message or  alt

Comment: so now you want to display an error message but wwould you please be specific where you want to add that error message

Comment: Vivek: C for those images which are not available i want to display an error message which i got through $(this).after("<br>Image was not found");, But the place is not appropriate, it displays as it is an alt, it displays in place of image, where i want to add it as suppose there is an image and i want to add it just below that image.

Comment: and when you write your code in jsfiddle, type your html in html section, javascript in javascript section and css in css section..then click on run..it will give you output in Result section.

Comment: Ya, This is displaying message where a images is supposed to display, But i want to add message juss below the image...supposing that there is an image an i am adding an comment below it. I hope you got it now what i want

Answer (score 1):

You can display error messages corresponding to your images something like this:

```
$('img').error(function(){
    $(this).after("<p>Image was not found</p>");
});
```

Or instead, you can show generic not-found image instead of those which were not found like this:

```
$('img').error(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'not-found image path');
});
```